# Docker - dynamic regex-based sed substitution in files

Tags: bash, docker, sed, docker-compose

I have various environment variables declared inside an `env_file` referenced in a `docker-compose.yml`

- `export FOO=bar`
- `export FAZ=baz`

In a config file within a container I reference these environment variables as such:

- `Today is a great day to ${FOO} and ${FAZ}`

I want to be able to capture all instances of text start with `${` and ending with `}` (ex. `${<SOMETHING>}`) and then replace it with the environment variable of key `<SOMETHING>`.

The following works in the shell, but I cannot get this to work with `sed -i` against a file, or within a bash script.

`echo "TODAY IS ${DAY}" | sed -r 's/(<foobar>\$[\w{}]+)/<foobar>/g`

- where the environment variable `DAY` is "FUNDAY" would produce: `"TODAY IS FUNDAY"`

Comment: Hi, I am checking out your problem but it is not so clear. What do you mean by "  want to be able to capture all instances of text start with ${ and ending with } (ex. ${<SOMETHING>}) and then replace it with the environment variable of key <SOMETHING>. " ?

Can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: If the conf contains ${Foobar}, I'm trying to replace it with the environment variable if the same key.  `Today is ${DAY}` --> "Today is Funday" if the variable with key `DAY` has a value of `Funday`.  Ultimately, this is to avoid manual mapping for every single variable.

Comment: I have voted to delete my answer as I have come to realize that it is totally off topic and did not help your cause. I have just understood your problem and I will present something which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks @UselessPerson - I realize that this is a pretty obscure problem to have and a fairly generic approach I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

I think i found something which may interest you. Please note that it complies to using only sed, in place editing and bash. Before we get into it, lets see the input and output:

**Environment file/variables:** As seen below, our file `"myenv"` has 3 variables and their values are as seen below.

```
%_Host@User> file myenv
myenv: ASCII text
%_Host@User> cat myenv
export FOO='This is FOO'
export BAR='This is BAR'
export BAZ='This is BAZ'
%_Host@User> env|egrep "FOO|BAR|BAZ"
FOO=This is FOO
BAR=This is BAR
BAZ=This is BAZ
%_Host@User>
```

**Target file to perform the operation upon:** Our target is to read the file `sample.txt` and replace values of variables with their actual values, if they are found in the loaded environment file. Our 4th line is not defined in our variable file so it should be untouched or unchanged.

```
%_Host@User> cat sample.txt
${FOO} is TRUE
${BAR} is TRUE
${BAZ} is TRUE
${BRAZ} is TRUE
%_Host@User>
```

**SCRIPT Result and final output:** To demonstrate, I am printing the lines as they are read from the target file `sample.txt`. If the variable inside the container (eg: `${FOO}` is found in any of the line, we replace the it with its value (eg: `This is FOO` in this case) which we can obtain from the `env`

```
%_Host@User> ./env.sh sample.txt ; cat sample.txt
[1.] Line is: [${FOO} is TRUE]
[1.] VAR:[FOO] has VALUE:[This is FOO]

[2.] Line is: [${BAR} is TRUE]
[2.] VAR:[BAR] has VALUE:[This is BAR]

[3.] Line is: [${BAZ} is TRUE]
[3.] VAR:[BAZ] has VALUE:[This is BAZ]

[4.] Line is: [${BRAZ} is TRUE]
[4.] VAR:[BRAZ] not found and NO CHANGE IN FILE !!

This is FOO is TRUE
This is BAR is TRUE
This is BAZ is TRUE
${BRAZ} is TRUE
%_Host@User>
```

As seen above, we have managed to change the `${FOO}` with `This  is FOO` as expected and left any other/s (which were not in our env file) untouched.

**SCRIPT and its working:**

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1

cfgfile="$1"

cat $cfgfile | while read line

do
        echo "[${i}.] Line is: [$line]"

        var=$(echo $line | sed 's#^.*\${\(\w*\)}.*$#\1#g')
        val=$(env |grep "$var"| cut -f2 -d"=")

        env|grep "${var}=" >/dev/null

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then
                echo "[$i.] VAR:[$var] has VALUE:[$val]"

                # Perform  inplace editing.
                sed -i "s@\${$var}@$val@g" "$cfgfile"
        else
                echo "[$i.] VAR:[$var] not found and NO CHANGE IN FILE !!"
        fi

        ((i++)) ; echo
done
```

Above script is following these steps:

1. `i=1` is just our counter. Not so important. Only for demo purpose.
2. `cfgfile="$1"` to accept file from prompt.
3. We cat the file and read it line by line in a while  loop.
4. We echo the line and then extract `FOO` from `${FOO}` and its actual value from env i.e. `This is FOO` and store it in `var` and `val`. simple enough.
5. We test whether this variable `FOO` is defined in `env` or not and check for command status.
6. If it is defined i.e. `$?` is `0` or `True`, we go ahead and perform in place editing or else we leave the line alone and no change.

I believe you should try your original command  with double quotes (") instead of single ('). It should work.

Please let us know if this was any useful.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate it.  I'll test this out and mark the answer accepted if it works out.  However, I've already shifted to using `envsubst` anyway.  Nevertheless, this is good to know for future bash scripting.

Comment: Please do and please let me know if you face any issues or would like to modify something. I am here to solve this one as it doesn't have an answer yet. Cheers!